# Why is my site scrollable horizontally without content?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm currently working on this site: [snoozyapp.com](http://snoozyapp.com) and the positioning works fine for desktop sizes, but when i shrink the window down or activate the Chrome mobile emulator the whole site becomes scrollable to the right with a white column without any content.

I just can't find the reason why this is visible as the whole html elements width goes to the visible area only.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Comment: It works fine for me ( using Chrome ). But you may use something like `body { overflow-x: hidden;}`

Comment: In Firefox and IE11 it also works fine.

Comment: as mentioned by @Seregmir the reason was word-break and one really long word. I guess different browsers default to different word-break behaviours in situations like this. For me, Mac-Chrome left the word untouched, even when the overall width was too small. Safari increased the width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

their is some hidden text that extends the width of the screen. Their are multiple ways to fix it but i prefer this one.

```
.content p { word-break: break-all; }
```

the reason is the text inside of this div, it helps me to add this line to my css to check these kinds of errors

```
*{ background-color: black !important; 
color: white !important; 
border: 1px solid red !important}
```

Comment: ah your debug snippet is gold! never thought about this. thanks!
the proble was one very large word, which was not broken without your mentioned break-all